# DB.eval() with Mongo Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I've prepared some script to execute on Mongo.
It works as expected from command line:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/dbName script.js
```

But when I tried to move it in java (scala) code it doesn't work with

```
db.eval(scriptContent)
```

Does anybody succeed with DB.eval() method?

Comment: eval() is not a good thing to use full stop, is there a reason why you need to run this script outside of Java?

Comment: Well. This script performs computations on two collections (mapReduce on first and iteration with computation on second), and merge result to the third one to perform further mapReduce operation. So I tried to avoid iteration over entire big dataset in Java. But if eval will not work as I expected, seems I need to turn all functions on collections into mapReduce ops.

Comment: Well it depends really, eval() does not work with sharding (last I checked) so if you expect to sharding these at some point I would say ditch eval.

Comment: Glad to have helped, sounds like your tasks could be better as incremental jobs that output bit a time until the merges and builds the full result set, could prolly make something interesting there, anyway again; glad to have helped :)

Comment: Re: Sammaye's comment on eval, also have a read of [Server Side code execution](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Using%7B%7Bdb.eval%28%29%7D%7D).  db.eval() will block for long running jobs.

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1**: Why does it need to be in Java? Can you just schedule the `mongo ...` command above to run via cron?

**Question #2**: Is it possible to implement via the Java driver instead?

The Java driver can execute Map / Reduce commands. You'll have to copy the javascript text into your Java code somewhere, but if you're working from the driver it can all be done there.

In fact one of the ideas behind the drivers is that they are just issuing DB commands like the shell. So you should be able to do everything from the shell OR from Java.

Comment: Q1: I would prefer to avoid spread logic across different components. So scheduled cron job is not an option.

Q2: Yes, I can. As I've already said in comment above I going to turn script (now mapReduce + iteration -> merge) into only mapReduce commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` VS running the script like this

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017/dbName script.js
```

are not equivalent. `eval()` sends the script to be executed on a mongod instance, whereas the command uses the driver to access the db.

As pointed out by others, `eval()` should be avoided as it has a lot of drawbacks, for instance, won't work on a sharded environment, or does not allow to create indexes in background.

Oh! and to answer the question, yes I did succeed with `eval()` in java. However, there are things that will simply not work ;)