# Calling Mongodb's load() function from Java

Tags: java, mongodb

(I am using Mongo Java Driver 2.12.0, and Robomongo.)

I am creating a mongo DB from java, and populating it with data all from Java. All that is working perfectly for me. I have made several javascript functions that I want in my database. If I insert these functions manually through the Robomongo shell using:

```
load('<path>\javaScriptFunction.js');
```

and call these in java through db.eval() these functions are running perfectly. Now what I want to do is that I want skip the step of loading these functions through Robomongo, and I want to load them to Mongodb directly through java. Now I have tried to load these functions to mongodb using java by executing the above mentioned load command through db.command(), and db.eval(), but none of these seem to be working.

Is there are any other way to execute raw shell commands through java? How can I perform the task of loading javascript functions to mongodb through java?

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks. I spent a complete day on it, yet could not find any reasonable result online.

Comment: `eval()` is used for passing JavaScript to the server to execute.  I don't believe there's a way in the driver to point to a script file on the server and get it to execute that - is that what you're looking for? You might also find the answers here useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781824/db-eval-with-mongo-java-driver

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can point to a file either.
But you can use eval ( only works on primary server).
If you really want to do it, you might get the content of the file using Java and pass it to a eval function as:
db.eval(your script)